# iOS Group Containers backed up?

Tags: ios, file, backup

so i know that some, or let's say nearly all, files are backed up on iOS.
I know how to prevent them from being backed up.
To maybe save unnecessary work i wanted to know if the content of
`containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:`
is being backed up too?
I couldn't find anything specific about the group containers in the [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) from apple. In [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html) it is said that the directories are stored in `~/Library/Group Container/`. In [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) it is written that all subdirectories of Library are backed up by iTunes. Does this now also mean that the content of my Group Container is also backed up or maybe not?
Maybe someone of you already has experience with that and can exactly tell me what's done with the content of the Group Container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an iOS developer myself this is an important question. After some hunting, I found this [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/18750178):

> AppGroup folder does not backed up (sic) via standard iCloud/iTunes backup procedure

This was reported as a duplicate of rdar://18396036 (Open) but it cannot be found.

Responses from Apple:

> If this issue is still occurring, please include any relevant logs, and or a test case with your update. (Oct 30, 2014)

and

> Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed (Nov 12, 2014).

It sounds like the intended functionality is that app group folders should be backed up, and there may have been a bug in iOS 8.0 preventing this which is fixed in iOS 8.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bounty rewarded.

Comment: So, this means AppGroup now can be backup to the iCloud ?